# Xcode Google Signin Button Image And Text not showing in Iphone

Tags: objective-c, button, google-signin

I'm following link steps and setup google login with pods
[Google Login Integration Link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)

When i run my app, i can show google sign-in button text and image in simulator but not showing in my device. i can show only blue button.
(i add view that inherit from GIDSignInButton, not button).

how can i solve the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this ?

Comment: unfortunately i don't